# In C++ how to replace one of the command line arguments with a string of different length

Tags: c++, arrays, string, command-line-arguments

I have a large C++ program in which several command line arguments can be provided using `char *argv[]`. Later in the program, the first argument needs to be replaced with a new string of some arbitrary length.

I first tried doing this in the simple way:

### MyProg_1.cpp

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  using std::cout; using std::endl;
  std::string new_string;

  //Confirm the command line arguments on the screen:
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i){
     cout << "argv[" << i << "] = " << argv[i] << "   String length = " << strlen(argv[i]) <<  endl;
  }
     cout << endl;

  // Change the value of one of the arguments:
  new_string = "ABCDE";
  strcpy(argv[1], new_string.c_str());

  //Confirm the command line arguments on the screen:
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i){
     cout << "argv[" << i << "] = " << argv[i] << "   String length = " << strlen(argv[i]) << endl;
  }

}
```

I compile and run it as...

```
$ g++ MyProg_1.cpp -o MyProg_1.x
$ ./MyProg_1.x abc def ghi
```

And I get the following output

```
argv[0] = ./MyProg_1.x   String length = 9
argv[1] = abc   String length = 3
argv[2] = def   String length = 3
argv[3] = ghi   String length = 3

argv[0] = ./MyProg_1.x   String length = 9
argv[1] = ABCDE   String length = 5
argv[2] = E   String length = 1
argv[3] = ghi   String length = 3
```

So it assigns the value of `new_string` to argv[1] correctly, but messes up the value of `argv[2]`, which I would like to preserve to the original value (`def`).

So in my next attempt I tried to store the values of `argv` into a temporary string array, in the hope that I could restore the values of `argv[2]` onwards after altering `argv[1]`.

### MyProg_2.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  using std::cout; using std::endl;

  std::string argvtemp[argc];
  std::string new_string;

  //Store all the command line arguments in a temporary array:
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i){
     argvtemp[i] = argv[i];
     cout << "argvtemp[" << i << "] = " << argvtemp[i] << "   String length = " << argvtemp[i].length() <<  endl;
  }
     cout << endl;

  // Change the value os one of the arguments:
  new_string = "ABCDE";
  strcpy(argv[1], new_string.c_str());

  //Restore the rest of the argv elements
  for(int i = 2; i < argc; ++i){
     strcpy(argv[i], argvtemp[i].c_str());
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i){
     cout << "argv[" << i << "] = " << argv[i] << "   String length = " << strlen(argv[i]) << endl;
  }

}
```

Again, I compile and run it as...

```
$ g++ MyProg_2.cpp -o MyProg_2.x
$ ./MyProg_2.x abc def ghi
```

And this time I get the following output

```
argvtemp[0] = ./main4.x   String length = 9
argvtemp[1] = abc   String length = 3
argvtemp[2] = def   String length = 3
argvtemp[3] = ghi   String length = 3

argv[0] = ./main4.x   String length = 9
argv[1] = ABCDdef   String length = 7
argv[2] = def   String length = 3
argv[3] = ghi   String length = 3
```

This fixes the problem with `argv[2]` but now messes up the modified value of `argv[1]`, which should have been `ABCDE`.

Just to clarify, the output I would like to see is:

```
argv[0] = ./main4.x   String length = 9
argv[1] = ABCDE   String length = 5
argv[2] = def   String length = 3
argv[3] = ghi   String length = 3
```

How do I achieve this? It seems to me that the lengths of the individual `argv` elements are somehow not changing even after I modify their values.

Unfortunately I don't have enough expertise in C++ to be able to do this and could not find an answer on the web.

Comment: Why do you need to modify `argv` directly anyway? Usually you'd parse the command line arguments once and convert them into something else that is easier to use

Comment: I would try `char new_string[] = "ABCDE";
argv[1] = new_string;`:

Comment: @UnholySheep Yes, you have a totally valid point and as a coder (coming from a non-C++ background) this is the sort of thing I would avoid doing. My problem is, I am dealing with a large legacy code, written by someone else, in which argv is passed onto another function, which then processes it in some complicated way. So I do not want to disturb that part of the code. However, I need to modify the code such that the value of one of the arguments, `argv[1]`, would be modified half way through the code.

Comment: The most troubling fact is "_I have a large C++ program_". Make every effort to not have that. Do have isolated thingies doing stuff well and it'll be easier.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a large C++ program in which several command line arguments can be provided using char *argv[]. Later in the program, the first argument needs to be replaced with a new string of some arbitrary length.

You simply cannot do that in a portable way (assuming you want of course [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) to be aware of the updated arguments). You could find some Linux specific tricks doing that.

Of course you could do `argv[i] = "foo";`  in your `main` (or some other function called from it), if `i>=0` and `i<argc`. But `ps` is likely to not see it.

But why cant you just copy the `argc` and `argv`  passed to `main` as heap variables, and process these?

On Linux, read about [parsing program arguments with `glibc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html). See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Consider also [using some `std::vector<std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)  and fill it early in your `main` from `argc` and `argv`

Comment: What is forbidden in `argv[1] = some_char_ptr:` ?

Comment: This is not forbidden, but you are not guaranteed that `ps`  would see the updated thing

Comment: `"foo"` is `const char[4]` whereas `argv[1]` is (non const) `char*`.